# A generalisation of the theorem of Maschke

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

The theorem of Maschke tells us that every representation of a finite group is the direct sum of irreducible representation. More precisely:

Let $G$ be a finite group, $K$ a field whose characteristic does not divide the order of $G$, $V$ a $K$-vector space of finite dimension and $\rho:G\to {\rm GL}(V)$ a representation of $G$. If $W$ is a $G$-invariant vector space of $V$, then there exists a $G$-invariant complement $W'$ such that $V=W\oplus W'$.

Now, I would like to prove or to find a counter-example to the following generalisation:

Let $G$ be a group  **such that every element has finite order**, $K$ a field of characteristic $0$, $V$ a $K$-vector space of finite dimension and $\rho:G\to {\rm GL}(V)$ a representation of $G$. If $W$ is a $G$-invariant vector space of $V$, then there exists a $G$-invariant complement $W'$ such that $V=W\oplus W'$.

Comment: @The User: why do they generate a finite subgroup?

Comment: If the finite orders of elements are uniformly bounded, this was proved by Burnside. It seems a bit too much to believe that it would work otherwise. I would speculate that one should be construct a counter-example using a construction of Golod-Shafarevich of such groups from nil-algebras...

Comment: This was exactly *not* proved by Burnside. The assertion that a finitely generated group with $x^n=1$ for all elements x is finite, is exactly Burnside's problem and is known to be *false* for large enough exponents. However: This might just work out if we do not work in $G$ itself, but in the image of $G$ in $GL(V)$, because linear groups are much better behaved than general infinite groups when it comes to these kinds of problems. I do not know off the top of my head whether or not Burnside's problem is true for linear groups or not.

Comment: @Vladimir You are right, in this general setting we cannot assume that.

Comment: @Johannes Hahn: I was referring to the result on linear groups which was indeed proved by Burnside himself: a linear group with $x^n=1$ for all $x$ is finite. (It is weaker than the result of Schur on periodic groups mentioned below which is crucial to establish this generalisation). So no need to be so dismissive right away.

Comment: @Vladimir: I had no intention to be dismissive of your post and I apologize if it sounded like that. I simply wanted to correct what I though was an erroneous statement. I misinterpreted what you were referred to when you wrote that "this" was proved by Burnside. The comments (one of them deleted by now) before that were referring to a finite subgroup of G and it is certainly false, that f.g. subgroups of G have to be finite. Only after passing to the image in $GL(V)$ this is true and that's what I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your expected generalization is true. Without loss of generality, you may assume that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(V)$. A linear group whose elements have finite orders is locally finite, that's an old Theorem by Schur, and contained for instance in Wehrfritz's book *Infinite Linear Groups*. Now take a maximal linearly independent subset $S$ of $G$, so $\langle S\rangle$ and $G$ have the same invariant subspaces on $V$. By Schur, $\langle S\rangle$ is finite, so your generalization holds by Maschke.

Answer (score 4):

I. Schur explicitly proved that every periodic subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is completely reducible ( Corollary 36.3 in Curtis and Reiner's "Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras", Wiley and Sons, 1962), improving earlier results of Burnside,

Comment: Even though your answer comes a bit late, it's always useful to provide a reference like this for a classical result rather than just sketching a proof.  No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @JimHumphreys : I missed the question at the time, and just noticed it. I was motivated to give the reference to clarify what Burnside had done about subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ (periodic such subgroups of bounded period are finite) and Schur had done ( finitely generated periodic such subgroups are finite and, in general, such periodic subgroups are completely reducible).