# Suppose that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ with finite exponent. Then is $G$ a finite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

As title. the exponent of $G$ is the least number $n$ (if exists) such that $g^n=e$ holds for all $g\in G$ or $+\infty$.

Comment: The answer  is yes (Burnside, Schur etc). I think this question has been answered before on this site.

Comment: By the way, you are using "n" in two completely different ways in this question. Also, the fact that $G$ is a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ should probably be in the body of the question, not just in the title.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Could you please give me a link where this question has been answered?

Comment: I can't remember where on here (you could search yourself though), but you can find the relevant material in section 36 (page 250 on---) of Curtis and Reiner "Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras" (Wiley, 1962)

Comment: I was possibly thinking of this (somewhat different) question, where the answers within it at least implicitly answer the question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130557/a-generalisation-of-the-theorem-of-maschke

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I think this is a interesting question. Thank you for your mark.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson eh, thanks for your undownvoting, though I don't really care about that... Or maybe I had better say I don't know what's the usage of this vote, I'm new here...

Comment: Maybe you had meant "thanks for your remark"? I think I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, I meant "thanks for your remark". Excuse me, I'm new to English, too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I was unable to find where else in MO this was answered, I'll answer this here. You can find a proof in chapter I, section 5 (pp. 83-84) of Algebra IV: Infinite Groups, Linear Groups by Kostrikin and Shafarevich; here's a Google books [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=O9cATtl-fowC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=matrix+group+%22finite+exponent%22&source=bl&ots=OXyJkBami5&sig=t16MzHgZ_eGvkw6Zp9Om8uoZLgk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qSoEVbHUEoLEggSWsIOQCA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=matrix%20group%20%22finite%20exponent%22&f=false).

Comment: The proof is very elegant, thank you very much!